# Getting the filepath from a biblatex entry

Tags: biblatex, bibtool

I'm struggling with getting the file paths properly from a biblatex entry. I'm toying around with this particular one, formatted by Zotero's Better Biblatex:

```
  File      = {/home/fbence/.vim/plugged/bibtexcite.vim/test/Abdai et al. - 2018 -
          Methodological challenges of the use of robots in
          ethological research.pdf;/home/fbence/.vim/plugged/bibtexcite.vim/test/Abdai2.pdf}
```

The first filename has a number of spaces in it, and it is saved in the biblatex entry with a lot of newlines and tabs. I was hoping I could use `bibtools` to handle this issue for me, but I haven't been able to figure out out to limit it's output to a single key in an entry.

I'm either looking for a way to get it with `bibtools` as that seems more robust then me hacking away at it, or alternatively, I'm looking for the rules to correctly parse back an arbitrary biblatex key with all the inserted newlines and tabs to the correct amount of spaces.

**Clarification**

- the actual filepath on disk is fairly normal, with single spaces between words, the newlines and tabs only appear in the formatted .bib file due to reflow and indentation
- my aim is to retrieve the value of the file key for consumption by another program (ultimately to open the pdf)
- my current approach is using `bibtool` to retrieve the entire entry and then using regex to get the file key's value and then trying to strip newlines and tabs, but this seems flaky (it already doesn't work on another users system), so I'd rather delegate the issue to a more mature tool

Comment: What's your use case for paying attention to the `file` field? Please elaborate.